# pooled proportions with confidence intervals

Tags: r, confidence-interval, proportion

I have some data like:

```
           Var1        Var2 
Study1     20/23      3/23
Study2     30/34      4/34
Study3     1/30       29/30
```

I would like to calculate pooled proportions with confidence intervals using R.

Comment: Why?  One has to ask due to the severe differences in proportions found by Study3 compared to the first two studies.  Pooling seems likely to give results that reflect none of the studies at all.

Comment: I would guess that this is a trick question that you were asked to see whether you would spot that there is anything wrong with simply doing that

Comment: It is invented data, I just wanted to get a function to do it using R. Thank you!